# How to get your Azure Table Connection String (json) in the latest version of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, azure

I noticed that Microsoft has made some code library changes to MVC\Azure Storage that seem to have broken my MVC code. I'm using a repository pattern. I can't seem to get the new documentation figured out.

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to do. Oh, and if you're feeling extra helpful a basic example of it with a set of generics `<T>` would be even more appreciated. There's just too many wrong answers on the Internet to sort through. I'm using Ninject for Dependency injection into my service layer. I tried to make my example as simple as possible so that everyone can see my using statements and basic code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
//Intellisense paints json red
//using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json;
//this one paints my IConfiguration interface red
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;

namespace Farmantix.Amity.Website.Repositories
{
    public class TableStorageRepository
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        IConfiguration config;
        CloudTableClient tableClient;
        CloudTable table;

        public TableStorageRepository()
        {

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("config.json");
            var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();


            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                config.Get("MicrosoftAzureStorage:[Name of Connection String]"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the specific nuget version you're using for Microsoft.Framework.Configuration? According to their GitHub issue tracker, the assembly name and namespace of Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel has been changed to Microsoft.Framework.Configuration. Configuration class name is changed to ConfigurationSection. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25